# what's the process for template function when need to instantiate the same type again later

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
int fun(T){
  return 0;
}
int main(){
  fun(0); //#1
  fun(1);  //#2 
}
```

Firstly,at the point of call for #1,the complier need to instantiate the template function for type "int"(implicit instantiation), then use the result of instantiation for "fun(0)",this process is no problem,but at the point of call for #2,does the complier directly use the result of above instantiation for #2  or make any other process(such as the complier will instantiate for #2 but find the instantiation for type "int" above then stop the instantiation and use the result above)?In other words,does the instantiation for #1 participate the overload resolution when #2 is called?

Update:
my other question is that whether the already instantiation(#1's implicitly instantiation) participate the overload resolution when encounter the same call(here is #2)?

Comment: Looking through the [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) process, instantiation doesn't play a part since it only relies on function declarations. What would be the consequences one way or the other?

Comment: @kmdreko The consequences  is that whether the complier need to deduce and substutite again,If in the substutition context which has stateful meta,and the subsequent results will be quite different

Comment: The compiler will insert a call to the method fun<int> at both invocations, and will let the linker figure it out later on. On the first invocation, the compiler should specialise the function for int (or as a final step, the ordering here is unimportant, and merely a compiler detail).

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function in an expression that is not part of an unevaluated operand constitutes an odr-use of that function [[basic.def.odr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#3). An odr-use requires a definition of the function to exist [[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4). Since your example does not explicitly specialize or explicitly instantiate the function template, it will be implicitly instantiated due to being referenced in a context that requires a definition to exist [[temp.inst]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.spec#temp.inst-4). And this is pretty much all the C++ standard has to say on the matter as far as I'm aware.

Thus, how exactly your compiler handles this is up the implementation of the compiler. In practise, I very much doubt any sane implementation would go through the full template instantiation process every time something in the source code requires an implicit instantiation. I'm not a clang nor GCC developer, but based on a [quick](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_90/include/clang/Sema/Sema.h#L7947) [look](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/pt.c#L20402) into the source code of each, it would seem to me that both, clang and GCC, will simply remember which implicit template instantiations are required and actually perform them at the end of the translation unit, or check whether an instantiation already exists and only perform the instantiation once…

Comment: your answers are very useful,but my second question is that whether  the defination of the already exisited instantiation(by implicit instantiation or explicit instantiation) participate the overload resolution